# Срочно нужно прогружать библиеотеку json, но python не виит отрибут load

Tags: python, json, python-3.7

Вот скрин[image: СКРИН]

Что делать?! Подскажите пойжалуста вопрос срочный

Answer (score 4):

Никогда не называйте собственные скрипты именами стандартных модулей. Так вы затеняете имя стандартного модуля и не сможете его импортировать.

Причина ошибки в том, что в **вашем** “json.py”, который вы импортируете, отсутствует функция “load()”.